# Access Child Property from Parent, Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, multi-module

I am new to Java. I am trying structure my project using multimodules of Maven. I have a **Maven** project which  has two child modules. I wonder if it is possible to **access a child property from the parent**. Because upon my researches it was not possible, I wonder if there is a way out.

Comment: By moving child property to a parent?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is possible. What are you trying to do?